# How to update table based from two different tables in php MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables reservation, orders, and inventory. In reservation i have orders for example (2 apples and an orange).(reservation.confirmation=orders.confirmation). I would like to update apple and orange inventory.sold when reservation.status changed to "Delivered"

```
reservation
---------------------------
confirmation | status

EX-10          pending


orders
---------------------------
confirmation  | product    |  qty

EX-10           apple         2
EX-10           orange        1


inventory
---------------------------
id            | nameofproduct | sold

1               apple           -->update to 2
2               orange          -->update to 1
```

HERE is my code so far.

```
$confirmation = $_POST['confirmation'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET status='$status' WHERE reservation_id='$roomid'");
    if ($status=='Delivered')
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE inventory SET sold = (SELECT qty FROM orders where confirmation='$confirmation') where nameofproduct=(SELECT prduct FROM orders where confirmation='$confirmatioin')");

        }
```

Please help for the right query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about `TRIGGERS`? See: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

I've made you what you want, I didn't check it so probably has errors, let me know if you have problems with it.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER inventory
AFTER UPDATE ON reservation FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE product VARCHAR(200); -- SHOULD BE THE SAME TYPE AND LENGTH AS order.product
        DECLARE qty INT;  -- SHOULD BE THE SAME TYPE AND LENGTH AS order.qty
        DECLARE orders_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT o.product, o.qty FROM orders o WHERE o.confirmation = NEW.confirmation;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;



        IF (NEW.status = 'delivered') THEN
            open orders_cursor;
            get_orders: LOOP

                FETCH orders_cursor INTO product, qty;

                IF finished = 1 THEN
                    LEAVE get_orders;
                END IF;

                -- UPDATE INVENTORY
                UPDATE inventory i SET i.sold = qty WHERE i.nameofproduct = product;
            END LOOP get_orders;
            close orders_cursor;
        END IF;


END
$$
```

Comment: hey barbarity thank you for the effort, should i put this code in my php script. (newbie)

Comment: this is my first time i am goin to try such thing so please be patient.

Comment: i already did this..,and i am getting this error CREATE TRIGGER inventory AFTER UPDATE ON reservation FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Sorry, delimiter was missing. Try now.